# Powershell loop to read a text file

Tags: powershell

I am looking how to create a script that gets the first line of a text file then runs a command then gets the second line of the text file and runs a command again etc ...

Here is a piece of code I had done but it just fetch a line and run the command.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDQSS.png)

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Please do not add code as image. Instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66814000/edit) your question and insert the code as [formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like -

```
$file = Get-Content -Path "D:\test.txt"
foreach ($line in $file){
  //Run the command
}
```